# ¿Por qué xaml pone mis variables como null?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows, wpf, xaml

Estoy desarrollando una app de punto de venta, el error viene cuando quiero usar una variable asignada con la propiedad `Name` de las etiquetas, en el codigo me las pone como null.
Al principio pensé que solo era algún error tonto de escritura, pero al parecer no. Luego probé cambiando el atributo `Name` a `x:Name` y tambien cambiando su valor, pero no funciono y seguia arrojandome NullObjectExceptions.
Finalmente le agregé a otro elemento el atributo y depuré a ver si ese no salia null y al parecer tambien crea la variable, pero no le da el puntero al objeto.
[image: Depuracion]

No se que hacer para solucionarlo. Aqui el codigo.

```xml
<Window x:Class="Pulse.Ventanas.Productos"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pulse.Ventanas"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Title="Productos"
        Width="600" Height="450"
        MinHeight="450" MinWidth="450">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- No se porque este es null -->
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="dataGrid"/>
        <DockPanel 
            Margin="5"
            Grid.Row="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <DockPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
                </Style>
            </DockPanel.Resources>
            <!-- Ni este -->
            <Button Content="Agregar" Name="btnAg" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
            <Button Content="Eliminar" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
            <Button Content="Editar" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Pulse.Ventanas
{
    public partial class Productos : Window
    {
        private Utils.ServerConn conn = new();

        public Productos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            getProductos(App.token);
        }

        private async void getProductos(string token)
        {
            var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            data.Add("token", token);
            string productos_json = await conn.post("get_productos.php", data);
            if (productos_json == null)
                return;
            var productos = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Models.Producto[]>(productos_json);

            dataGrid.ItemsSource = productos; // Error NullObject
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

¿Acaso será porque la variable es local y esta es destruida antes de haber sido creada?
Eso sería tonto

```cs
private void ClickProductos(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    btn.IsEnabled = false;
    var productos = new Ventanas.Productos();
    productos.Show();
    productos.Closed += (o, e) =>
    {
        btn.IsEnabled = true;
    };
}
```

Comment: ¿A caso `Deserialize()` no toma ningún parámetro?

Comment: @Mateo 
Ay, lo puse mal, igual ese no es el error, eso si funciona ya lo depure mil veces a ver si todo bien y esta bien

Answer (score 1):

Puede que el problema que tengas venga de que cuando se llama la función aun no se ha cargado toda la ventana, y por eso los controles que intentas llamar aun sean `NULL`.

Prueba de poner el siguiente código para ver si esto soluciona tu problema:

```
public Productos()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
    {
        return;
    }

    getProductos(App.token);
}
```

Lo que hace esto es comprobar si el `New` se esta llamando des del diseñador, si es el caso, como no ha inicializado aun todos los controles hacemos el `return`, si no se llama des del diseñador, entonces tendría que estar todo cargado correctamente y podria seguir para adelante con el proceso normal.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente los botones no estén instanciados aún. El evento que te garantiza que el árbol de controles ya está procesado, es Loaded. Puedes probar a colocarlo dentro del manejador, por ejemplo así:

```
public Productos()
{
      InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (o, e) =>
        {
            getProductos(App.token);
        };
}
```

Aquí puedes consultar el ciclo de vida de los elementos en WPF https://docs.microsoft.com/es-ES/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/object-lifetime-events?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8